# Ruby SQLite3 bind_params

Tags: ruby, string, sqlite, equality

I'm having an issue with Ruby SQLite.  This is my code,

```
require 'socket'
require 'sqlite3'

server = TCPServer.open(1337)
DB = SQLite3::Database.new "./Tavern.db"
loop {
    Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
        input = client.gets
        input = input.gsub '\n', ''
        input = input.split(' ')
        case input[0]
        when 'register'
            stmt = DB.prepare "INSERT INTO Managers (name, job, location, busy)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, 0)"
            stmt.bind_params input[1], input[2], client.addr[3]
            stmt.execute
        when 'request_job'
            stmt = DB.prepare "SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE job = ? AND assigned = 0"
            stmt.bind_params input[1]
            results = stmt.execute
            puts results.next
        end
    end
}
```

Where `input[1] = "test"`

If `stmt.bind_params input[1]` is changed to `stmt.bind_params "test"`, the sql query works, if it is left as is, it doesn't.  I've checked to make absolutely sure that "test" and input[1] are equal with == and by using .bytes on both of them and manually comparing.

Any ideas on why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `stmt.bind_params( 15, "hello" )` style syntax as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. It turned out that the string I was using had a different encoding than the encoding that was required.

Check what `input[1].encoding` and `"test".encoding` yield! If they are different, use the `force_encoding`-method.